# Thread - Request Mergers of Very Similar Questions

Tags: feature-request, exact-duplicates, merging

Would something perennial like [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes, etc. (volume 10/2012 - 12/2014)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-votes/11433#11433) help? Example:

♦ [$\sqrt{x}$$\sqrt{x}$ = $x$ but $\sqrt{x^2}$ = $|x|$. Why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215796/sqrtx-sqrtx-x-but-sqrtx2-x-why),
 ♦ [What's the thing with $\sqrt{-1} = i$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13801/whats-the-thing-with-sqrt-1-i),
 ♦ [Why is $\sqrt{4} = 2$ and Not $\pm 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380359/why-is-sqrt4-2-and-not-pm-2),
and their  many duplicates under "Related" (sufficiently multitudinous that I record only these 3).

Posterior to the comments and downvotes, I've added "homogeneous" to the title to define this thread for coalescing very allied questions and answers, such as duplicates, and not merely all those which are related. I tender some candidates in my answer below.

I reference [When, and how, to suggest merging of questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9758/when-and-how-to-suggest-merging-of-questions),
[questions asked over 100 times](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12369/questions-asked-over-100-times?rq=1),     [Merging two identical questions with accepted answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10771/merging-two-identical-questions-with-accepted-answers?rq=1)

Comment: The merging of questions can only be done by moderators. Even then, for search indexing reasons, or because of the required amount of editing to the answers to make them fit neatly with the other question (notation etc.) it may be better to keep them separate.

Comment: I like the concept of the Requests for Reopen Votes thread a lot, the idea can certainly be extended to do other things in a more democratic manner too, and we are planning to steal this good idea to implement community moderation on our [future new physics site](http://tpproposal.wordpress.com/) too ... ;-P ;-)

Comment: In general I’m not in favor of merging questions that are not duplicates.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I emended my OP; I should've written "duplicate."

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, do you extend that to near-duplicates by the same user (sometimes because they don't realize they can edit their question)?

Comment: @dfeuer: It depends very much on the specific case, but in general I prefer to err on the side of keeping them distinct.

Comment: Sundry related similar threads — http://math.stackexchange.com/a/11875/85100

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207485/prime-factors-of-a-positive-integer-greater-than-its-square-root  
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/417912  
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/528768

Comment: "I've added "homogeneous" to the title to define this thread for coalescing extremely similar and allied questions and answers, such as duplicates, and not merely all those which are related." That's not what "homogeneous" means.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thank you. I'm using it in the sense of "consisting of parts all of the same kind"? Is this wrong? Please advise.

Comment: No one question consists of parts, all of the same kind.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thank you. I emended it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised why this thread isn't more popular or voted in favour for. I had quite some trouble reading and comparing these very similar threads and think they'd benefit from merges.

**[Proof the maximum function $\max(x,y) = \frac {x +y +|x-y|} {2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457177/proof-the-maximum-function-maxx-y-frac-x-y-x-y-2?rq=1)**
[Show that the $\max{ \{ x,y \} }= \frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429622/show-that-the-max-x-y-dfracxyx-y2?lq=1)
[How to prove this simple statement: $\max\{a,b\}=\frac{1}{2}(a+b+|a-b|)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258934/how-to-prove-this-simple-statement)

**[Good book for self study of a First Course in Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62212/good-book-for-self-study-of-a-first-course-in-real-analysis)**
[best book for real analysis for undergraduate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682332/best-book-for-real-analysis-for-undergraduate?lq=1)
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474780/a-good-book-on-analysis?rq=1
[Good First Course in real analysis book for self study](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/188255/79539)
[Book Recommendations and Proofs for a First Course in Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317753/book-recommendations-and-proofs-for-a-first-course-in-real-analysis?rq=1) and others.

**[Text recommendation for introduction to linear algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/445115/79539)**
[A First Course in Linear Algebra Text](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/143904/79539)
[What is a good book to study linear algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/160056/79539)
[A Book for Linear Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/605596/79539) and others.

**[How to define the $0^0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/259514/79539)**
[Zero to the zero power - is $0^0=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11150/79539)
[Proofs for $0^0 =1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/566782/79539)
[Is there any good reason not to define $0^0=1$ , such as contradictions in algebra or arithmetic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/606719/79539)
[Why is $0^0$ undefined?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/283902/79539) and others.

**[Reverse Triangle Inequality Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/127372/79539)**
[Prove one case of the Reverse Triangle Inequality $|x-y|≥|x|-|y|$ for all reals $x$ and $y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680966/prove-this-inequality-for-all-reals-x-and-y)
[How to prove $\lvert \lVert x \rVert - \lVert y \rVert \rvert \overset{\heartsuit}{\leq} \lVert x-y \rVert$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406443/how-to-prove-lvert-lvert-x-rvert-lvert-y-rvert-rvert-overset-heartsui?lq=1)
[Triangle Inequality with complex numbers: Prove that ||x|−|y||≤|x|-|y|.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488194/triangle-inequality-with-complex-numbers-prove-that-xyx-y?lq=1)
[Is it always true that $\|\vec{x} + \vec{y}\| \geq \|\vec{x}\| - \|\vec{y}\|$ over $\mathbb{R}^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128410/is-it-always-true-that-vecx-vecy-geq-vecx-vecy-ov?lq=1)   and others.

**[For every $\epsilon >0$ , if $a+\epsilon >b$ , can we conclude $a>b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508464/for-every-epsilon-0-if-a-epsilon-b-can-we-conclude-ab)**
[Showing $a \le b$ if $a \le b+\varepsilon$, for all $\varepsilon \gt 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680177/showing-a-le-b-if-a-le-b-varepsilon-for-all-varepsilon-gt-0?lq=1)
[Proof by contradiction: $ \forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}(a< b+\epsilon) \to a \leq b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622403/proof-by-contradiction-forall-epsilon-in-mathbbr0a-b-epsilon-t?rq=1)
[Proof : $ \forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}(0 \leq a<\epsilon) \to a =0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622430/proof-forall-epsilon-in-mathbbr00-leq-a-epsilon-to-a-0?rq=1)   and others.

Answer (score 0):

Please mind that I don't record all the similar threads found under "Related" for each link.

♦ [Best book ever on Number Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329/best-book-ever-on-number-theory),

♦ [Good abstract algebra books for self study](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54839/good-abstract-algebra-books-for-self-study),

♦ [In classical logic, why is $(p\Rightarrow q)$ True if both $p$ and $q$ are False?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48161/in-classical-logic-why-is-p-rightarrow-q-true-if-both-p-and-q-are-false),

♦ [Proving $\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} dx = \dfrac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-e-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2),

♦ [What are good books/other readings for elementary set theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11177/what-are-good-books-other-readings-for-elementary-set-theory),

♦ [Intuition behind Matrix Multiplication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31725/intuition-behind-matrix-multiplication),
[Matrix multiplication: interpreting and understanding the process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24456/motivation-behind-definition-of-matrix-multiplication),
[Matrix Multiplication Interpretation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354047/matrix-multiplication-interpretation)

♦ [Is this proof correct for : Does $F(A)\cap F(B)\subseteq F(A\cap B) $ for all functions $F$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225333/is-this-proof-correct-to-prove-fa-cap-fb-subseteq-fa-cap-b-for-all-fun?rq=1),
[functional equality of unions/intersections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75247/functional-equality-of-unions-intersections/75254#75254),
[Maps - question about $f(A \cup B)=f(A) \cup f(B)$ and $ f(A \cap B)=f(A) \cap f(B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239783/maps-question-about-fa-cup-b-fa-cup-fb-and-fa-cap-b-fa-cap-f?rq=1),
[$f[A\cap{B}]\subseteq{f[A]}\cap{f[B]}$ but show proper inclusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496795/fa-capb-subseteqfa-capfb-but-show-proper-inclusion)
[Image of Intersection of sects not equal to intersection of images of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482633/image-of-intersection-of-sects-not-equal-to-intersection-of-images-of-sets)

Answer (score 0):

I don't want this to be converted to a trivial answer, thence I'm writing this.

[If $p$ is prime, then the kth root of $p$ is irrational, $(p^{\frac 1k}) $, for any integer $k>1$, prove it's irrational by assuming it is rational](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520355/if-p-is-prime-then-the-kth-root-of-p-is-irrational-p-frac-1k-for?rq=1)
[$ p^{\frac1n} $ is irrational if $p $ is prime and $n>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324724/p-frac1n-is-irrational-if-p-is-prime-and-n1?lq=1)
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504409/let-p-be-a-prime-k-1-show-that-sqrtkp-is-irrational?lq=1
[$ p^{\frac1n} $ is irrational if $p $ is prime and $n>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324724/)

---

[Is $n^{th}$ root of $2$ an irrational number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11872/is-nth-root-of-2-an-irrational-number/11875#11875)
[Prime factors of a positive integer greater than its square root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207485/prime-factors-of-a-positive-integer-greater-than-its-squar)
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/417951/85100
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/528768/85100

---

[Prove that if $a^n\mid b^n$ then $a\mid b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/309023/85100)

[Suppose a, b and n are positive integers. Prove that (a^n) | (b^n) if and only if a | b.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/572537/85100)

[Does $a^n \mid b^n$ imply $a\mid b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351623/does-an-mid-bn-imply-a-mid-b?lq=1)